# Transform flat array of objects into nested objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I have an array of task objects and I want to transform these into a multidimensional object grouped by `ownerID`

```
var tasks = [   
{taskID: "1", title: "task1", ownerID: "100", ownerName: "John", allocation: 80},       
{taskID: "2", title: "task2", ownerID: "110", ownerName: "Sarah", allocation: 50}, 
{taskID: "3", title: "task3", ownerID: "110", ownerName: "Sarah", allocation: 50}, 
{taskID: "4", title: "task4", ownerID: "120", ownerName: "Mike", allocation: 25},
{taskID: "5", title: "task5", ownerID: "120", ownerName: "Mike", allocation: 45}];
```

This is my expected output:

```
var people = {

    100:    {   ownerName: "John", 
                tasks:  {       
                            {taskID: "1", title: "task1", allocation: 80}
                        }       
            },

    110:    {   ownerName: "Sarah", 
                tasks:  {       
                            {taskID: "2", title: "task2", allocation: 50}
                            {taskID: "3", title: "task3", allocation: 50}
                        }       
            },

    120:    {   ownerName: "Mike", 
                tasks:  {       
                            {taskID: "4", title: "task4", allocation: 25}
                            {taskID: "5", title: "task5", allocation: 45}
                        }       
            },


    };
```

I'm looping through the original data and assigning each row

```
people[ownerID] = {};
person = people[ownerID];
person['ownerName'] = ownerName;
person['tasks'] = {};
person[taskID] = {};
task = person[taskId];
task['taskID'] = taskID;
```

This seems to group by `ownerID` fine and creates a nested object of tasks but it will only add one task for each person.

Argh. Any help really appreciated.

Comment: `tasks` should be an array, not an object.

Comment: @NinaScholz why? would I still be able to access individual tasks using people[100].tasks[3].title if they were an array?

Comment: i was wondering, which data type you are using. the above is not a valid example. if you need properties, which reflects the `taskID`, then you need to use it in the example as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
people[ownerID] = {};

person['tasks'] = {};
```

These lines don't check if an object with the same key exists before and create a new object each time.

Try changing it to

```
people[ownerID] = people[ownerID] || {};

person['tasks'] = person['tasks'] || {};
```

Comment: Amazing. So simple. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a functional way to do it (assuming *ownerName* is functional dependent on *ownerID*):

```js
const tasks = [   
  {taskID: "1", title: "task1", ownerID: "100", ownerName: "John", allocation: 80},       
  {taskID: "2", title: "task2", ownerID: "110", ownerName: "Sarah", allocation: 50}, 
  {taskID: "3", title: "task3", ownerID: "110", ownerName: "Sarah", allocation: 50}, 
  {taskID: "4", title: "task4", ownerID: "120", ownerName: "Mike", allocation: 25},
  {taskID: "5", title: "task5", ownerID: "120", ownerName: "Mike", allocation: 45}];

const result = tasks.reduce( (acc, {taskID, title, ownerID, ownerName, allocation }) => {
    (acc[ownerID] = acc[ownerID] || { ownerName, tasks: [] })
        .tasks.push( { taskID, title, allocation } );
    return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Nice it works. Is there anyway you could provide some explanation to what you mean as functional dependent? I am actually just getting started with functional programming.

Comment: *ownerName* is functional dependent on *ownerID* when it is always true that given a value for ownerID, there can be only one value for *ownerName* associated with it, never two.

Comment: Nice, I like it.

Answer (score 0):

Just one thing, the tasks should be an array, since objects can't hold another objects without having a key.

```
var tasks = [   
{taskID: "1", title: "task1", ownerID: "100", ownerName: "John", allocation: 80},       
{taskID: "2", title: "task2", ownerID: "110", ownerName: "Sarah", allocation: 50}, 
{taskID: "3", title: "task3", ownerID: "110", ownerName: "Sarah", allocation: 50}, 
{taskID: "4", title: "task4", ownerID: "120", ownerName: "Mike", allocation: 25},
{taskID: "5", title: "task5", ownerID: "120", ownerName: "Mike", allocation: 45}];

var transformed = tasks.reduce((obj, item)=> {
    if(!obj[item.ownerID]) {
        obj[item.ownerID] = {};
    }
    obj[item.ownerID].ownerName = item.ownerName;
    if(!obj[item.ownerID].tasks) {
        obj[item.ownerID].tasks = [];
    }
    obj[item.ownerID].tasks.push({taskID: item.taskID, title: item.title, allocation: item.allocation})
    return obj;
}, {})
console.log(transformed);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the logical OR as default operator ans assign a new object if the peroperty does not exists.

```js
var tasks = [{ taskID: "1", title: "task1", ownerID: "100", ownerName: "John", allocation: 80 }, { taskID: "2", title: "task2", ownerID: "110", ownerName: "Sarah", allocation: 50 }, { taskID: "3", title: "task3", ownerID: "110", ownerName: "Sarah", allocation: 50 }, { taskID: "4", title: "task4", ownerID: "120", ownerName: "Mike", allocation: 25 }, { taskID: "5", title: "task5", ownerID: "120", ownerName: "Mike", allocation: 45 }],
    people = {};

tasks.forEach(({ taskID, title, ownerID, ownerName, allocation }) => {
    people[ownerID] = people[ownerID] || { ownerName, tasks: {} };
    people[ownerID].tasks[taskID] = people[ownerID].tasks[taskID] || { taskID, title, allocation };
});

console.log(people);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```